# Как использовать Ray на земле Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Делаю 3д Игру
Есть персонаж Морской конёк
Есть земля с горами
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы с помощью Рея он проверял землю и есть земля есть, то был от нее на какой то высоте, грубо говоря имитация что конёк под водой
Столкнулся с проблемой , что персонаж при входе в гору меняет свой Rotation и поднимается под наклоном. В общем я не понимаю как сделать так чтобы он не наклонялся когда поднимался в гору, а просто поднимался в гору не меняю наклон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f; // Скорость движения   
    public float rotationSpeed = 5f; // Скорость поворота   
    public float distToGround; //Дистанция до земли


    public Rigidbody rb; // 

    public Camera cam;

    public GameObject JellyfishModel; // Моделька

    Vector3 movement; //напрвление перса

    public Ray MouseRay;               // Луч, вдоль которого мы пускаем 
    public LayerMask TerrainMask;       // Фильтр по которому мы отсеиваем все, кроме песка

    private void Awake()
    {

        TerrainMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Terrain");     // Создаем фильтр по слою Terrain
    }

 void Update()
    {
        GroundChexk();

        movement.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        movement.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        //поворот игрока на мышку
        MouseRay = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); //создаст луч который будет использовать экран камеры
        float hitDist = 0.0f; //расстояние попадание на землю
        Plane playerPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward * 30f, Color.red);

        if (playerPlane.Raycast(MouseRay, out hitDist) && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 targetPoint = MouseRay.GetPoint(hitDist); //Возвращает точку в единицах измерения вдоль луча. hitDist расстояние попадания
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPoint - transform.position); //расщёт повора цели
            targetRotation.x = 0; // чтобы мы не повернули ее непо той оси
            targetRotation.z = 0;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 7f * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        //поворачивался по направлению движения
        if (movement.magnitude > Mathf.Abs(0.5f))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation/*начальная точка*/,
                                 Quaternion.LookRotation(movement)/*куда хотим смотреть */,
                                 Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);

        }

        //Ходьба
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //двигаемся

    }


    void GroundChexk()
    {
        Ray isGround = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);


        if (Physics.Raycast(isGround, out var hitInfo, distToGround * 10f, TerrainMask)) //луч,точка,дистанция до земли,земля
        {

            Debug.DrawRay(isGround.origin, isGround.direction * distToGround, Color.green); //показывает луч
            //создаём новую переменую Разница . Точка где луч пересекат землю y + дистанция до земли минус позиция по y
            var dif = (hitInfo.point.y + distToGround) - transform.position.y;
            //Направление перса равно вверх умножить на разницу
            movement = Vector3.up * dif;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код текстом. Чтобы отформатировать блок как код, надо 4 пробела вначале каждой строки или символы ``` в конце и начале блока кода на новой строке.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы заблокировать наклоны необходимо постави галочки Freeze Rotation в настрйках RigitBody соответствующие необходимой оси наклона

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]